# I'm using Zend Studio for Eclipse and I'm trying to save my file but it failed!

Tags: php, ubuntu

I'm new to PHP development and I just used Zend yesterday. One problem I'm having is saving the file in a directory that is read-only.

I'm using Zend studio to develop PHP scripts. I have XAMPP installed in my Ubuntu in /opt/lampp/ directory.

Now the /opt/lampp/htdocs directory requires privilege access. I can't save anything there. It requires me to sudo everything. I know this is for security reason.

Now, I can just sudo gedit index.php inside the opt/lampp/htdocs/project directory and save the file there. But I want to use my Zend Studio to develop scripts.

When I opened the file inside /opt/lampp/htdocs/project/index.php inside Zend. I can't save it there. The save could not be completed because parent of resource is marked as read-only

Now I dont want to modify the directory to be read/write, I just want to use Zend Studio and allow zend to save files inside the directory.. Please guide me!

Comment: are you sure this is programming related?

Comment: uhmm, i'm positive that this is programming related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, short of running Zend itself under sudo, I'm not sure you're going to be able to do that.

You're asking how to be able to write to a write-protected directory. The answer is "Don't try".

You'll either have to unprotect it or figure out a way to have Zend make a copy of the file in an unprotected area for editing, then copy it back (under sudo) when you close it.

I know which  option I'd choose (I'm inherently lazy).

Comment: Hi, yeah I used the latter technique. But can you tell me how to unprotect a write-protected directory? Then I'll just turn on the protected again once I'm finish editing?

Comment: Assuming you own the directory: "chmod u+w <directory>", then "chmod u-w <directory>" to revert. Or "sudo chmod 777 <directory>" to fully open it up but you'll need to know what to set it back to (e.g., if it was originally drwxr-x---, that would be "chmod 750 ...").

Comment: Wow thats some hard to remember numbers. I'll note it in my tomboy notes! thanks!!

Comment: Keira, you just have to divide up the permissions: rwxrwxrwx is rwx (read,write,execute) for owner, group and other in that order. A single rwx is represented in binary where r represents 4, w represents 2 and x represents 1 - just add 'em together. Thats why rwxr-x--- is 750.

Answer (score 0):

Run Zend Studio under the privilegies required to save to */opt/lampp/htdocs/*?

Comment: i dont know how to run zend studio in command line. i tried sudo zend index.php but it didn't work.

Comment: In Ubuntu, you need to find the *.desktop file for Zend - it will show you the command line to use. I don't have an Ubuntu box handy to find out where they are for sure, but I think they'll be in /usr/share/applications.